# convert a string into a two-dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert a string like this `"10|15|1,hi,0,-1,bye,2"` where the first two elements `10|15` mean something different than `1,hi,0,-1,bye,2`. I would like to separate them from each other. A naive way to accomplish that would be:

```
value = string.split("|");
var first = value[0];
var second = value[1];
var tobearray = value[2];
array = tobearray.split(",");
```

(Of course, if you know a way to do this in a better way, I'd be glad to know).
However, `array` is an array which contains `array[0]=1, array[1]=hi, array[2]=0, array[3]=-1`, etc. However, I want to obtain a two dimensional array such as

```
array[0][0]=1, array[0][1]=hi, array[0][2]=0
array[1][0]=-1, array[1][1]=bye, array[1][2]=2
```

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want a multi-d array instead of a sparse array-like object {10: [1,'hi',0], 15: [-1,'bye',2],}?

Comment: @kojiro: Well, I was using google-dif-match-patch which produces array(array())'s, therefore, in order to maintain consistency I chose to use multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Robert ah, I see. Just curious!

Comment: @kojiro: It's ok. Should I be worry about performance?

Comment: Not if your arrays are really this small! ;) Seriously, I would expect the object to be less efficient than the array, but depending on use, possibly easier to work with.

Comment: @kojiro: Each array of array is that small (3 elements), however, there could be a considerable number of initial arrays.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first two elements (`10|15`) can be extracted beforehand. After that you're left with:

```
var a = "1,hi,0,-1,bye,2";
```

Let's *splice* until we're left with nothing:

```
var result = [];

a = a.split(','); 

while(a[0]) {
    result.push(a.splice(0,3));
}

result; // => [["1","hi","0"],["-1","bye","2"]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function getMatrix(input_string) 
{
    var parts = input_string.split('^');
    for (var t=0; t<parts.length; t++)
    {
        var subparts = parts[t].split('*');

        parts[t] = subparts.splice(0,subparts.length);              
    }

    return parts;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getMatrix(input_string) {
    var parts = input_string.split('|');
    var subparts = parts.pop().split(',');
    var partlen = subparts.length / parts.length;
    for (var i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
        parts[i] = subparts.splice(0,partlen);
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Comment: Oh, very nice!. Unfortunately, J-P posted a very good solution earlier. +1, though. Thanks :-)