# how to make string as array in java script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a string value like:

```
1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;a,b,c;d,e,f;g,h,i
```

I need to convert it into array in JavaScript like

```
1 2 3

4 5 6 

7 8 9

etc.
```

Can any one please suggest me a way how to do this?

Comment: Google for "Javascript Split"

Comment: do you mean multidimensional array?

Comment: here's a previous answer that may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163709/convert-a-string-into-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split). In your case, you need to split twice. Once with `;` to split the string into chunks, then separately split each chunk with `,` to reach the array structure you are looking for.

```
function chunkSplit(str) {
    var chunks = str.split(';'), // split str on ';'
        nChunks = chunks.length, 
        n = 0;

    for (; n < nChunks; ++n) { 
        chunks[n] = chunks[n].split(','); // split each chunk with ','
    }

    return chunks;
}

var arr = chunkSplit("1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;a,b,c;d,e,f;g,h,i");
```

Comment: what exactly is the first ";" for in the line `for (; n < nChunks; ++n) {`? is that there to find the character ";". I am asking because I usually see some sort of expression before the ";" in a for loop

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var yourString = '1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;a,b,c;d,e,f;g,h,i';
var array = [];
yourString.split(';').forEach(function(value) {
  array.push(value.split(','));
});
```

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ynT3Y/)
- Note: `.forEach()` not supported in IE <=8

Comment: This does NOT work. Did you even try running your code? The value of `split` in your `for...in` loop is the index in the array, not the value.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `Array.forEach` does not have universal browser support. http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Answer (score 1):

If you need a multi-dimensional array you can try :

```
var array = yourString.split(';');

var arrCount = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrCount; i++)
{
  array[i] = array[i].split(',');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The following split command should help:

```
 yourArray = yourString.split(";");
```

Comment: Note that there are also commas. It looks like the OP wants to split the results again to get a two-dimensional array.